# IE11 present XML transformed by defined stylesheet

Tags: xml, internet-explorer-11

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 with Internet Explorer 11 with RDP users. I need them to view XML files with style sheet defined from the local file system within internet explorer.  Currently internet explorer will only prompt to download the XML file and will not present the XML transformed with the style sheet. How can I get internet explorer on Windows Server 2012 present XML through style sheet in the browser?

Top of the XML loaded from the local file system looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit\QuickBooks 2020\components\payroll\ROE.xsl"?>
<ROEHEADER FileVersion="W-2.0" SoftwareVendor="Intuit Inc." ProductName="QuickBooks Payroll" ProductVersion="30">
```

Comment: Your code looks correct as per this document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms754529(v=vs.85) I suggest trying to set the IE browser as the default app for displaying XML files in the Settings. It may help you to display the file in the IE browser.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT thanks for the response. Setting XML to use IE11 as the default program is something that would had previously tried without success.

Comment: What happens if you right-click the XML file and click on 'Open with' option and select the IE browser from the list? Does it display the file or download it?